# What's the utility of the name attribut in HTML?

Tags: html, attributes

So. I am confused abbout the utility of the name attribut in HTML.

Am I right if I say that the value of the "name" attribut is used sever-side to recognize an HTLM element (i.e. `<form>, <iframe>, <meta>`) and eventually manipulate it ?

i.e. `<form action="server.php" name="information">...</form>`
"information" is the name given to the `<form>` element server-side??

Comment: You are almost there, the name attribute can be used for getting the element by referencing by name in JavaScript. It is a good practice to do it.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the form name to identify and reference the form elements in javascript like:

var formRef = document.forms['information']; // 'information' is form name

var fName = formRef.elements['firstName'];   // 'firstname' is element inside form

However, using an ID attribute for form rather than a name is generally preferable. Whereas, name attribute is necessary on all form elements when the form is submitted to server side code.